# How to rewrite specific values of a file through PHP?

Tags: php, variables, fwrite

```
<?php
  $info = "Hi";
  $file = fopen("file.txt","w");
  fwrite($file,$info);
  fclose($file);
?>
```

I am currently using the code above to write a value into a text file. However, is it possible to retrieve certain variables that are stored within that text file and just rewrite them instead?

Example:

**file.txt**

```
$one = "first";
$two = "second";
$three = "third";
```

Through PHP code, a specified "variable" in the text file should have its contents changed.

**New file.txt**

```
$one = "first";
$two = "hi";
$three = "third";
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more further?

Comment: Use `include` (or require) and overwrite the variable after the include.

Comment: Maybe you can load every line brake in array? Then you can change what you want so you can re-create the file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have some PHP code written in a file, file.txt. If you have only stored variables, I believe you can get away with some regular expression to do what you want.

Nevertheless, for anything more complex (maybe even for this specific case), I would recommend that you use some PHP parser to parse all the variables and their values, and make your changes accordingly. ([here's a PHP parser written in PHP](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser)).

EDIT:

Just to clear things up, a simple replacement will not suffice. Imagine you have something like `$first = "a";`, and then you decide to replace `a`, with `\`. A naive replacement, would leave you with `$first = "\";` in your file.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use str_replace() to replace the variables with the data you like

```
$s_input = 'this is a #first text';

$a_repfr = array('#first', '#second', '#third');
$a_repto = array('funny', 'php', 'love');

$s_output = str_replace($a_repfr, $a_repto, $s_input);
```